# How to configure ufw on Ubuntu and still retain internet connection?

Tags: ufw

I am having trouble with how to configure ufw firewall for my Ubuntu 13.04 VPS server. Each time I enable the firewall, it closes all connections to the server. I need to open the following ports. I have installed LAMP and PhpMyadmin, Mono-complete and nano (as my text editor). I need to open non-standard ports as I am running opensimulator.

First set of rules (allow)

Second set of rules (deny out)

```
sudo ufw deny out 1:19/tcp
sudo ufw deny out 1:19/udp
sudo ufw deny out 25:52/tcp
sudo ufw deny out 25:52/udp
sudo ufw deny out 54:79/tcp
sudo ufw deny out 54:79/udp
sudo ufw deny out 81:122/tcp
sudo ufw deny out 81:122/udp
sudo ufw deny out 124:442/tcp
sudo ufw deny out 124:442/udp
sudo ufw deny out 444:8999/tcp
sudo ufw deny out 444:8999/udp
sudo ufw deny out 9010:99999/tcp
sudo ufw deny out 9010:99999/udp
sudo ufw deny out 10001:65535/tcp
sudo ufw deny out 10001:65535/udp
```

If someone could guide me through how to get this done it would be greatly appreciated as I can't understand why it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

To check your current settings:
`sudo ufw status verbose`

To add basic firewall rules:

`sudo ufw deny 5353/udp

sudo ufw deny 5900/tcp

sudo ufw deny 22

sudo ufw deny 25/tcp

sudo ufw deny 135,139,445/tcp

sudo ufw deny 137,138/udp

sudo ufw deny 110

sudo ufw deny 2049

sudo ufw deny 143

sudo ufw deny 21/tcp

sudo ufw deny ssh`

To block Outgoing Ports Except Those Needed (This configuration will allow the following outbound ports: 20-21, 53, 80, 123, 443 which is all that is required for many users):

`sudo ufw deny out 1:19/tcp

sudo ufw deny out 1:19/udp

sudo ufw deny out 22:52/tcp

sudo ufw deny out 22:52/udp

sudo ufw deny out 54:79/tcp

sudo ufw deny out 54:79/udp

sudo ufw deny out 81:122/tcp

sudo ufw deny out 81:122/udp

sudo ufw deny out 124:442/tcp

sudo ufw deny out 124:442/udp

sudo ufw deny out 444:65535/tcp

sudo ufw deny out 444:65535/udp`

Re-check your changes:

`sudo ufw status verbose`

Re-check enable (required):

`sudo ufw enable`

Comment: Thank you for your answer it has partially answered my question. In the rules above half of the incoming ports are missing (8000:8010, 9003, 9050:9055) and in the first set of rules it says deny ssh/22 would that not stop me being able to connect using putty. Are there any ubuntu consultants I can hire to configure it for me. It's important that I get it right as I'm using the server at present with all ports open (using shut down to block the ports when I'm not using it - not a good solution I know but I can't get ufw configured properly). I'm happy to pay for this to be done.

Comment: @user230293 I guess, I can refer you here : http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1204-lts-server-part-1-basics. Also, if I helped you, you can up vote my answer or can select it as accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: That was very helpful if i could ask you to explain the 1st set of rules above (as i understand the logic to the deny out rules and have amended them to reflect the ports that in need open): in the first set of rule the ports I want opened you are using deny 22/23 etc and the first two port numbers 5353/udp and 5900/tcp what do these ports do and why would i need them open. If I can understand what the rules are doing I think i may be able to get it working.